# .htaccess rule FilesMatch to all subfolders (subfolders was randomly created)

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I tried to find solution here, but I don't. I working with htaccess every day but I have one problem which I can't solve.

I have directory structure:

```
/cmd/user_files/**[random_folder]**/avatars/pic.jpg
```

In `/cmd/user_files/` I have more folders which randomly created over some app. Under every that randomly created folders I have some files and pictures which I don't want to access from public, and I have one subfolder "avatars" for which I want to show only .jpg

I created `.htaccess` in `/cmd/user_files/` and I added this:

```
order allow,deny
deny from all
allow from 127.0.0.1
```

With this I deny access to every file and subfolder under `/cmd/user_files/`.

Now, what I need to add to this `.htaccess` that I can show `.jpg` from

```
/cmd/user_files/[random_folder]/avatars/*.jpg
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using mod_auth... it may be easier to use mod_rewrite instead. For example, in the `/cmd/user_files/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule !^[^/]+/avatars/.*\.jpg$ - [F]
```

This blocks (403 Forbidden) access to all files/folders except the URL-path that matches the regex `^[^/]+/avatars/.*\.jpg$` (relative to the `/cmd/user_files/` subdirectory).

**UPDATE:** Note the `!` prefix on the `RewriteRule` *pattern* - this *negates* the regex. This is an Apache operator, it's not part of the regex itself.

*Side note...* `order allow,deny` are Apache 2.2 directives. If you are on Apache 2.4+ then there is a different syntax.

Comment: Thank you very much. Works like a charm.
Can you tell me please do you know where I can check online my regex with url ?
I tried with some online regex test but without success. Thank's mate ;)

Comment: For general regex testing, I like https://regex101.com/ - but if you are testing regex to be used with mod_rewrite then you naturally need to be aware of what you are testing against. Notably, in the above directive, it is the URL-path only, _without_ a slash prefix. For _simple_ mod_rewrite (`.htaccess`) testing then https://htaccess.madewithlove.be/ is often referenced - however, be aware there are limitations/bugs with this tool.